# Multinational page head Google Analytics code differently

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, header, google-analytics-api, head

I created a multinational page using Polylang. I need to put the Google Analytics code in the head, but I want to put it differently in Korean and English.

Currently, the header is used together, the footer is loaded differently, and the English Google Analytics code is placed separately in footer-en.

Is it possible to load the Google Analytics code differently in the head without using a plugin?

```
\<!-- Code to load footer-en when the homepage is in English --\>

if( get_bloginfo('language') == 'en-US' ) :

get_footer('en');

else:

get_footer('');

endif;
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting GA codes differently? I guess that would be an easier way for you to distinguish the lang of web-pages, for example from the fullPagePath dimension or page_location you have the URL, and usually there is language parameter, no?  And as much as I know, GA codes should be in head and body tags and not in the footer